# CSS/JS Files Inaccessible via Folder Path, Accessible Only via Direct .html

Tags: javascript, html, css, path, directory

So I am having a problem where my purely HTML/CSS/JS site can only reach the CSS/JS files via the direct index.html link, and not the folder path. To clarify, my URL's are structured as follows:

1) `http://<site>.com/css/main.css`

2) `http://<site>.com/why-you-should-fly/index.html`

I am trying to keep all of my URLs tidy, which is why there is an index.html in `2)` - so that I can link directly to the page via `http://<site>.com/why-you-should-fly/` (which will automatically jump to the index.html).

My problem is that when I am using just the folder path (`http://<site>.com/why-you-should-fly/`), none of my CSS or JS files seem to load. When I go directly to the .html file, though, the CSS and JS seems to load perfectly `http://<site>.com/why-you-should-fly/index.html`).

In `2)`, I am referring to the CSS file with the following code:

`<link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Any ideas as to why this may be happening would be greatly appreciated. To note: I have the same files on two different servers - for some reason the CSS/JS loads perfectly on one server, but fails to load on the other (even after multiple reuploads).

Comment: This surely has to do with the server configuration. Is it running on your own server ? Do you know/have access to its configuration ?

Comment: So the problem is as follows - the first server, which is the one that I have access to, is the one where `../css/main.css` is correctly linked to. I am pushing the files to a client that, for security reasons, can not provide me direct access to the second server, which is his. Is there a precise question I can ask about configuration that would bypass the need to see his server myself?